# Writing text at the bottom of align equation environment

Tags: equations, align, numbering

I have a set of equations, and some texts are to be written in between those equations and also some text at the bottom of the equations. I am using the following code

```
\begin{align}
    a & = b \\
    \shortintertext{Some Text in between equations}
    c & = d
    \shortintertext{Some Text at the bottom of the equations}
\end{align}
```

but it creates an equation with equation number after the last command (\shortintertext{...}). The equation number I removed by using \nonumber, but the extra space I am unable to remove. Also, writing text outside the align environment creates more space between the equation and text (at the bottom).
Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: It is not clear, but if you simply insert the text after the `align` it will be in the next line of the paragraph. Maybe you are using a very large line spacing. Compare `\end{align}Some Text at the bottom of the equations`
`

Comment: @Sigur with "Compare \end{align}Some Text at the bottom of the equations", the output gives more line spacing after the equation "c=d" and "Some Text at the bottom of the equations", than that of line spacing between "Some Text in between equations" and "c=d". I want to have equal spacing in both cases.

Comment: For the number problem, use the `align*`  environment.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the comment, the numbering problem is solved using align*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name (short) intertext tells you that this is intended for material that should be set *between* aligned equations or, more generally, formulas.

You can use Celdor's idea, but I guess that you want that the alignment is followed by the usual space after the display.

The manual of `mathtools` tells us that the vertical space above `\shortintertext` is 3pt, so you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Some text that precedes the display
\begingroup
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{3pt}
  \begin{align}
    a & = b \\
    \shortintertext{Some Text in between equations, long enough.}
    c & = d
  \end{align}
  Some Text at the bottom of the equations\endgroup\\*[\belowdisplayskip]
Some text that follows the display.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the text following the display begins a new paragraph, you should not use `\\*`. Modify into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Some text that precedes the display
\begingroup
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{3pt}
  \begin{align}
    a & = b \\
    \shortintertext{Some Text in between equations, long enough.}
    c & = d
  \end{align}
  Some Text at the bottom of the equations\endgroup\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}

Some text that follows the display.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend to use a different way to express your ideas, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you please elaborate on what you mean by using a different way to express your idea

Comment: @PravinBehera It much depends on what those intertexts are about. You seem to think that they belong in the alignment, but they don’t, for a reader.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to change `belowdisplayskip` to `\jot`, just for this single case, and add the last line of text after the environment.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{\jot}
  \begin{align}
    a & = b \\
    \shortintertext{Some Text in between equations.}
    c & = d
  \end{align}
  Some Text at the bottom of the equations
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me.